# TextChanged event doesn't work.

Tags: c#, textbox, textchanged

I have a textbox in Form and i want to detect when the text has changed but the code I have found is giving me no joy.

I am probably missing something in the proporties or something you have to define before.

Here is my code:

```
private void tbxparkingTimesS1_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("You are in the ToolStripItem.TextChanged event.");
}
```

Thanks for any help with this trivial problem.

Comment: Can u pls show the designer code ?

Comment: What is the type and name of the item you have linked this code to? show us the code linking this to the item in question and showing where you expect the change text event to have been triggered

Comment: Have you wired this code to the event TextChanged using the Event Page on the property grid for the textbox tbxparkingTimesS1?

Comment: @Steve i dont think i have, im realy new to C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wire the TextChanged event to a particular method inside your code do the following

- Click on the TextBox inside your form
- Open the properties windows (press F4 or menu View -> Property Window )
- Select the event page (lightning icon)
- Double click on the TextChanged property line
- Insert your code inside the template build for you by Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks steve just worked it out before you posted this, this thanks all the same!

Answer (score 1):

Have you assigned the event handler to the textbox?

Normally this will be done "behind the scenes" by Visual Studio - with the result being an additional line of code in your .designer file.

Something like:

```
this.tbxparkingTimesS1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(tbxparkingTimesS1_TextChanged);
```

(It['s been a while since I've done webforms - so that might be slightly off)

Comment: i think that may be what i require, do you know where abouts in the .designer the code goes?

Comment: Don't make changes yourself on the designer.cs file. You risk to break your app or loose your changes.

Comment: Um - You don't really want be editing that file by hand. In Visual studio - click on your edit box - and then click on the little "Lightning bolt" icon, in the properties side-bar. Double-click into the "textChanged" event handler (or choose your event, if available from the drop-down) - and this should wire it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Double Click on Text box it will generate text change event for you.

```
    private void tbxparkingTimesS1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // implement your code here. 
    }
```

When you double click VS will create event handler in your designer.cs file as bellow

```
 this.tbxparkingTimesS1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tbxparkingTimesS1_TextChanged);
```

You can do the same by using property window events or create event on code behind.